# Qt cout matrix4x4

Tags: c++, qt, cout

I'm having trouble printing a qtmatrix 4x4.

```
QMatrix4x4 m = ...;
std::cout << m << std::endl;
```

I get the following error

```
cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue 
to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:581:5: error:   
initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& 
std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) 
[with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Tp = QMatrix4x4]'
```

From [Qt Matrix4x4 doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmatrix4x4.html#operator-lt-lt-39) it shows that I should be able to output it.

Comment: Actually Qt doc doesn't say you can output it using `std::cout`, because `std::cout` obviously can't handle `QMatrix4x4` type. Try to use `qDebug()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
QMatrix4x4 m = ...;
qDebug() << m;
```

As you can see in the ostream class documentation bellow, ostream class does not implement stream operator to classes different from the following list.

```
ostream& operator<< (bool val);
ostream& operator<< (short val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned short val);
ostream& operator<< (int val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned int val);
ostream& operator<< (long val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned long val);
ostream& operator<< (float val);
ostream& operator<< (double val);
ostream& operator<< (long double val);
ostream& operator<< (void* val);
ostream& operator<< (streambuf* sb );   
ostream& operator<< (ostream& (*pf)(ostream&));
ostream& operator<< (ios& (*pf)(ios&));
ostream& operator<< (ios_base& (*pf)(ios_base&));
```